# $ is not a function Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress site - that has a ton of custom code and plugins and all sorts of JQuery, and bootstrap, and frameworks, loading.

At the very bottom of the last loading footer - I place:

```
<script>

    if(window.jQuery){

        $(document).ready(function(){ 
          alert("I am ready."); 
        });

    }

</script>
```

and I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

Clearly - JQuery is loaded. I've tried placing other JQuery there as well - besides the on load - and I get the same error.

**Why do I get the $ not a function error?**

Comment: Try replacing `$` with `jQuery`. Does `jQuery(document).ready(function(){  ... });` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is loaded in safe mode in Wordpress. Try:

```
<script>

    if(window.jQuery){

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
          alert("I am ready."); 
        });

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that!
After all these years of working in WordPress. Is JQUERY in safe mode something relatively new?

Comment: I'm not sure when it was implemented but I know it's not new.